# How to continually split a list and separate remainder?

Tags: python, list, split

How would I go about splitting a list in two, but also leaving behind a remainder as its own "list"? For example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15]
```

Not only that, but continue halving each sublist to get this desired result:

```
[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13], [14], [15]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? When should the splitting stop?

Comment: I've tried splitting it once but didn't know where to go from there, and only managed to split into equal pieces. The splitting should stop when the pattern matches the bottom list, where its 2 lists of 3 followed by 1 "list" of 1 (as all of the lists I'm using will have a one remainder).

Comment: You can [edit] that into your question.

Comment: and your end condition is not very clear; your step two matches that same condition (two lists of equal length and a remainder). I've interpreted it instead as having lists that can't be further split without becoming single-value lists. So anything of length 3 and lower.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should do the trick:

```
def splitList(array):
    half = len(array) // 2 #find the halfway point
    return (array[:half], #get the first half
           array[half : half*2], #get the second half
           array[half*2 : half*2 + len(array)%2] #get the remainder
           )

array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
splitList(array)

>> ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g']
```

and then repeat however many times you want:

```
array = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']]
for x in range(n):
    newArray = []
    for sub in array:
        newArray += splitList(sub)
    array = newArray
    array = [e for e in array if e != []] #remove empty elements
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive generator:

```
def split_gen(lst, start=0, stop=None):
    if stop is None:
        stop = len(lst)
    size = (stop - start)
    if size < 4:
        yield lst[start:stop]
        return
    half = size // 2
    # two chunks of length half, plus an optional remainder
    yield from split_gen(lst, start, start + half)
    yield from split_gen(lst, start + half, start + (half * 2))
    if size % 2 == 1:
        yield lst[stop - 1:stop]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(split_gen([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13], [14], [15]]
```

Note that it doesn't produce intermediary lists; it just calculates the indices of the splits and only creates the final sublists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two functions, one to split the initial list to partial lists, and the other one to do recursive calls on the generated list until it cannot be split any further (`len(sub-list) <= 3`) for example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

def split_list(lst):
    if len(lst) > 3:
        n = len(lst) // 2  # integer division to get the size of the new sublists
        new_list = list([lst[0:n]])  # append sublist 1
        new_list.append(lst[n:n+n])  # append sublist 2
        new_list.append(lst[len(lst)-len(lst) % 2:])  # get remainder and append to list
    return split_sub(new_list)  

def split_sub(lst):
    chk = 0
    new_list = []
    for item in lst:
        if len(item) > 3:
            n = len(item) // 2
            new_list.append(list(item[0:n]))
            new_list.append(item[n:n + n])
            new_list.append(item[len(item) - len(item) % 2:])
        else:
            new_list.append(item)
            chk += 1
    if len(new_list) == chk:  # if this condition is met then all sub lists are of the size <= 3
        return new_list
    return split_sub(new_list)

print split_list(l)
```

The second function will keep running till all `len(sub-list) <= 3` which means it is done splitting and will return the final list.

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13], [14], [15]]
```